# MS Access How to Update Linked Table Path while Keeping the Format

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have around 20 linked tables in Access sourcing from .csv files, with the first row used as table headers. However, I can’t seem to keep the headers any time I update source path, so I have to manually delete and relink them every single time and it’s been painful.
Any idea how to keep the table format and properties after source path change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing a tabledef .connect property in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391447/changing-a-tabledef-connect-property-in-vba). Why is path changing?

Answer (score 1):

Can use VBA to modify links. Example code:

```
Dim td As TableDef
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strOld As String
Dim strNew As String
'replace the following strings as needed
strOld = "C:\Users\June\Forums"
strNew = "C:\Users\June"
Set db = CurrentDb
For Each td In db.TableDefs
    If InStr(td.Connect, strOld) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print td.name
        Debug.Print "Old Link: " & td.Connect
        td.Connect = Replace(td.Connect, strOld, strNew)
        td.RefreshLink
        Debug.Print "New Link: " & td.Connect
    End If
Next td
db.TableDefs.Refresh
```